# Is it possible to import WebSphere wsadmin as a jython module?

Tags: scripting, websphere, jython, websphere-7, wsadmin

In WebLogic, there's the WLST (WebLogic Scripting Tool) which is similar to WebSphere wsadmin.  The nice thing about WLST is that you can import it as a module into other jython code and use it without any dependencies.

Here's link that discusses this:
http://ghattus.com/2006/01/06/wlst-as-a-jython-module/

Is the same thing possible with WebSphere wsadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

wsadmin is "scripting framework" not originally created with jython in mind. It was intented to be used with TCL. After that it was "abstracted" so that (m)any popular scripting languages can be used inplace of TCL, and only Jython was provided by actual WAS instalation.

Leaving an api desing which is certainly not very pythonic or efficient.

Anyway neither of 5 main objects of wsadmin are python objects, and some of them are even constructed (like source code is being literally created with merging strings) as wsadmin loads.

But you can do something else. wsadmin can be run outside WAS as standalone program. And it can be even upgraded with jython 2.5, so you can run newer python code within wsadmin.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite some of the basic wsadmin functionality (such as checking server status) in Jython using that scripting framework?  We already have some tools written in Jython that monitor our WebLogic application servers, and I'd like to extend them to monitor WebSphere application servers too.  We can call wsadmin, but on Solaris it takes about a minute to just start up wsadmin and connect to a DMGR, which is unacceptable for our purposes.